# SNS Topics and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm in a situation where I need to process some notifications from a SNS topic. I'm thinking about processing this message in a Lambda function.
I have to implementation in mind

1. Subscribe Lambda function to the topic and process the notification
2. Subscribe a SQS queue (Fifo) to  the topic and then Lambda function
   will be invoked based on the notifications in the queue.

Order of the message is import for the consumer application. Keeping this in mind which one seems to be a better implementation. Any pointers/explanation would be helpful.

Comment: How strict is the ordering requirement?  What is the message velocity (i.e. 1 message a minute or 100,000 messages a second)?  Lambda may not be your best bet as it can't scale very well if the message ordering is absolute.

Comment: The frequency of the operation is pretty low - a few hundred notifications in an hour. Messages are related to life cycle of aws resources including applications - say created, deployed, deleted. So order is important for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds more like multiple somewhat independent message streams.  So if a `created` event for EC2-1 came in before one for EC2-2 there really isn't an issue.  In that case I would stick with the SNS -> Lambda method as the SQS method will require polling of the queue.  The Lambda won't cost anything if it's not being used but you will (eventually) get charged for SQS polling.

There are many examples of how to handle the messages coming in.  In Java, for example, you can use [POJO handlers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-pojo.html) (a plain old java object for which Lambda has done the deserialization for you or you could used [predefined objects](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/SNSEvent.java) that, in this case, are SNS specific.

Comment: It seems I have to add some clarification here - my earlier statement "aws resources" was too generic. Apologies for that. What I meant by aws resources was applications (like micro services). And each application has a lifecycle managed by one governance system (application). This will fire events for the topic. And the consumer here is a dashboard which displays the current status (thats why the order is important).

Comment: @kallada - I still feel that this is valid.  Unless your services are going through multiple state changes within milliseconds there shouldn't be any ordering issues

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just red that now lambda can use SQS as the event source to trigger the function to avoid polling. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/

Comment: Well, **you're** not polling but there is polling going on - from the link `There are no additional charges for this feature, but because the Lambda service is continuously long-polling the SQS queue the account will be charged for those API calls at the standard SQS pricing rates.`  Also be careful - again, from the link - `Lambda will automatically scale out horizontally consume the messages in my queue.` - ordering could be an issue depending on the service transition time.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe your SQS FIFO queues to an SNS FIFO topic. Then, you can have your queues trigger the Lambda functions, in order. Here’s an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/fifo-example-use-case.html